# Replace String with Anchor in Custom Twig Filter (Rendering issue)

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm writing a custom twig filter for my site, among other things it parses some text for URLs, and if it finds them it's supposed to replace the token with an anchor tag pointing to itself.

Code:

```
foreach ($tokens as $key=>$value)
{
  if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
  {
    // Replace $token with a version anchored to itself
    $tokens[$key] = "<a href='$value' target='_blank'>".$value."</a>";
  }
}

// Replace the spaces back in the string and return it
return implode(" ", $tokens);
```

Parsing and replacing seems to work fine, but upon rendering Twig doesn't render the replaced token as an anchor, but as a string (meaning I see the html rendered as text on the page).

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the raw filter of twig to don't escape the output of your function :

```
{{ my_function(myVar)|raw }}
```

see the doc : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

Comment: I'm not writing a Twig function, I'm writing a filter. Would I be able to call the raw filter in addition to my new filter? Something like

`{{ variable |myFilter|raw }}`

Comment: I think so, why not trying ?

Comment: Turns out Symfony allows chaining of filters. I'm still not 100% comfortable using raw, but currently it seems the best work-around.